# Print image in page mode using esc commands

Tags: c#, printing, escpos

Image is not printed in page mode using "GS v 0" command.
Here is my code:

```
private static string ConvertBitmapToCommandsForMode1(Bitmap bitmap, byte[] image = null)
{
    List<byte> commands = new List<byte>();

    var e = new ESCPOS_NET.Emitters.EPSON();

    //return BitConverter.ToString(commands.ToArray()).Replace("-", "");
    // 1. Select page mode
    commands.Add(0x1B); // ESC in hex
    commands.Add(0x4C); // L in hex

    // 2. Change horizontal and vertical motion units to set normal dot units
    commands.Add(0x1D); // GS in hex
    commands.Add(0x50); // P in hex
    commands.Add(0xB4); // Decimal 180 in hex
    commands.Add(0xB4); // Decimal 180 in hex
    // the printer will move 180 dots for every inch it moves horizontally or vertically.

    // 3. Direction
    commands.Add(0x1B); // ESC
    commands.Add(0x54); // T
    commands.Add(0x00);
    // print direction 0x00 would be left to right, 0x01 would be bottom to top, 0x02 would be right to left, and 0x03 would be top to bottom.

    // 4. Select the printing area for edge data
    commands.Add(0x1B); // ESC
    commands.Add(0x57); // W
    commands.AddRange(new byte[] {
        0x14, 0x00, // 0 (xL, xH)
        0x64, 0x00, // 0 (yL, yH)
        0x64, 0x00, // 100 (dxL, dxH)
        0x64, 0x00  // 100 (dyL, dyH)
    });
    // 0x90 0x01: These two bytes define the X coordinate of the upper-left corner of the printing area. The first byte (0x90) is the low-order byte, and the second byte (0x01) is the high-order byte. To get the X coordinate in decimal, you combine these two bytes into a 16-bit value: 0x0190 in hexadecimal is 400 in decimal.
    // 0x76 0x00: These two bytes define the Y coordinate of the upper-left corner of the printing area. Here, 0x0076 in hexadecimal translates to 118 in decimal.
    // 0x68 0x01: These two bytes represent the printing area width in dots. 0x0168 in hexadecimal is 360 in decimal.
    // 0x10 0x02: Finally, these two bytes represent the printing area height in dots. 0x0210 in hexadecimal is 528 in decimal.

    commands.Add(0x0A); // Line Feed
    commands.AddRange(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("123eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee"));
    commands.Add(0x0A); // Line Feed
    commands.Add(0x0A); // Line Feed

    // 5. Select the printing area for edge data
    commands.Add(0x1B); // ESC
    commands.Add(0x57); // W
    commands.AddRange(new byte[] {
        0x64, 0x00, // 100 (xL, xH)
        0x00, 0x00, // 0 (yL, yH)
        0xF4, 0x01, // 500  (dxL, dxH)
        0xC8, 0x01  // 200  (dyL, dyH)
    });
    
    // 6. Print Image
    commands.AddRange(e.PrintImage(image, true, true, 300));

    // 7. Print all data and cut
    // Print all
    commands.Add(0x1B);
    commands.Add(0x0C);

    // 8. Select cut mode and cut paper
    commands.Add(0x1D); // GS in hex
    commands.Add(0x56); // V in hex
    commands.Add(0x42); // Decimal 66 in hex
    commands.Add(0x50); // Decimal 80 in hex

    commands.Add(0x1B); // ESC in hex
    commands.Add(0x53); // S in hex

    return BitConverter.ToString(commands.ToArray()).Replace("-", "");
}
```

Result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TKre.png)

I've tried using the GS v 0 command for printing the image and the ESC L command for selecting page mode. Additionally, I've attempted to use the ESC * command, but the printed image has spaces between every 8-bit segment.

Comment: Their support may vary depending on the printer vendor and model. Please add the vendor and model of the printer you are using, as well as its command reference. Even if it is supported, it is currently a deprecated command, so it may be better not to use it. [GS v 0 \[obsolete command\]](https://download4.epson.biz/sec_pubs/pos/reference_en/escpos/ref_escpos_en/gs_lv_0.html)

Comment: it is epson TM-T88V. When i am using "ESC *", i get image with spaces between. "ESC 3" and "ESC J" not working there

Comment: tried this example https://download4.epson.biz/sec_pubs/pos/reference_en/escpos/ref_escpos_en/pagemode.html

Comment: same result:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/18D_z4BXNBXCP9XfyQjCLecx_9FRPB3QS/view?usp=sharing

Comment: That's strange. You may want to contact EPSON about the problem. Alternatively, how about redirecting the data of the example you tried to a file and analyzing it with my tool? [kunif/EscPosUtils](https://github.com/kunif/EscPosUtils)